# Creating waiting/busy indicator for executed process

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-interface

i've program which execute child process like

```
cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install")
log.Printf("Running command and waiting for it to finish...")
err := cmd.Run()
log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
```

While this command is running it download and install npm packages which take some time between 10 to 40 sec, and the user doesnt know what happen until he see the stdout (10-40 sec depend on the network) , there is something that I can use which prints something to the cli to make it more clear that something happen, some busy indicator(any type) until the stdout is printed to the cli ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use another goroutine to print something (like a dot) periodically, like in every second. When the command completes, signal that goroutine to terminate.

Something like this:

```
func indicator(shutdownCh <-chan struct{}) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Print(".")
        case <-shutdownCh:
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install")
    log.Printf("Running command and waiting for it to finish...")

    // Start indicator:
    shutdownCh := make(chan struct{})
    go indicator(shutdownCh)

    err := cmd.Run()

    close(shutdownCh) // Signal indicator() to terminate

    fmt.Println()
    log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
}
```

If you want to start a new line after every 5 dots, this is how it can be done:

```
func indicator(shutdownCh <-chan struct{}) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for i := 0; ; {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Print(".")
            if i++; i%5 == 0 {
                fmt.Println()
            }
        case <-shutdownCh:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try it and let you know :)

Comment: question, in case I use `cmd.start` and then `cmd.wait`  where is better to close the indicator ?

Comment: When the command completes, which in that case would be after `Cmd.Wait()`.

Comment: its working and creating dots one after another until it prints someting, is there a way to print just 3 dots and start again like `. .. ...` `. .. ...` ?

Comment: @RaynD For that you would need a 3rd party lib like [`termbox-go`](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go). You could however also print a newline after every 3 or 5 dots if that helps, no 3rd party lib is needed for that.

Comment: I dont want to use third party :), so you are saying that with you code it cannot be done ?

Comment: You want to manipulate text already written to the terminal, the standard library does not have support for this. You may do this with some terminals by printing control characters, but that solution is not portable.

Comment: and your suggestion to print new line, how can I know when to print new line, any example ?

Comment: btw the lib https://github.com/kyu-suke/wot which you provide as reference is using a game as waiting indicator :) , for me it's a bit overkill...

Comment: im closing the question, it will be great if you can add example for your suggestion "You could however also print a newline after every 3 or 5 dots if that help" , thanks!

Comment: @RaynD Added example how to start a new line after every 5 dots.

Comment: do you mean someting like this`
 i := 0
 ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
 defer ticker.Stop()
 for {
  select {
  case <-ticker.C:
  
   fmt.Print(".")
   i++
   if (i==3){
    fmt.Println()
    i = 0
   }
  case <-shutdownCh:
   return
  }
 }` ?

Comment: `func indicator(shutdownCh <-chan struct{}) {
 
 i := 0
 ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
 defer ticker.Stop()
 for {
  select {
  case <-ticker.C:
  
   fmt.Print(".")
   i++
   if (i==3){
    fmt.Println()
    i = 0
   }
  case <-shutdownCh:
   return
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to turn icza's answer around. Since the npm command is a long-running execution, it would probably be better to use a goroutine for it instead of the ticker (or both as a goroutine), but it's a matter of preference.

Like this:

```
func npmInstall(done chan struct{}) {
    cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install")
    log.Printf("Running command and waiting for it to finish...")

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("\nCommand finished with error: %v", err)
    }
    close(done)
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go npmInstall(done)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(3 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Print(".")
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println()
            return
        }
    }
}
```